# How do I calculate the statistical power of my survey results? It is an exploratory survey with no measurements

Tags: statistical-significance, statistical-power, survey

I need to prove that my survey results or sample size is statistically significant. I did a 2 sample T test in R, where my supervisor said that "what is the statistical power of your results is not clear from this". I think t test will not apply to my data as mine is exploratory survey, with Yes, no answers, so no continuous data.

What test do I need to do to show my results are statistically significant or to calculate statistical power of my results? For background I did the survey in 6 months, sample size is 40 completed out of 71 total responses. Please guide thank you.

Comment: to compare two samples of "yes/no" data, the standard technique is called the "two sample Z test for proportions". This will tell you if the percent of people saying yes is different between two groups; is that what you're hoping to learn?

Comment: If you're trying to calculate post-hoc power, please don't. There should be ample discussion on this site and on the internet about why that's a bad idea.

Comment: You shouldn't be conducting post-hoc power analysis. This blog post may help you answering to your supervisor: http://daniellakens.blogspot.com/2014/12/observed-power-and-what-to-do-if-your.html

Comment: First, as others said, you shouldn't do post-hoc power analysis. Second, you say you did a t-test and then you say you can't do a t-test.   Also, I am not sure what "40 completed out of 71 total responses" means. Do you mean 31/70 refused to answer?

Comment: Hi peter, yes 31 responses were incomplete, so we excluded them for analysis

Comment: I am trying to prove that my sample size is statistically significant or representative of the population (I surveyed architects in 2 countries), for this purpose my supervisor is saying to calculate power of my results, how should I go about this?

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your comment, I am just trying to prove that my survey sample is sufficient or representative of a larger population but I am unsure how to do this. One of my supervisor has asked my to do a power analysis, and I am just clueless how to go about it

Comment: @Maha You should mention what you're trying to test or learn (i.e. what are your research hypotheses?). It's difficult to suggest an appropriate method without knowing why it will be used for. If you want to convey how uncertain the results are due to the sample size, using confidence intervals or credible intervals *might* be appropriate for this purpose, but you probably have to tell us more about what you want to learn from your data (without using any statistical technical language like "significance" or "power").